# Did the treaty of Versailles require closure of German cadet schools?

Tags: military, education

I'm hoping someone can give me a definitive answer about whether German military schools/academies ("kadettenanstalt" - secondary school level) were forced to close by the Treaty of Versailles. It seems I once read this somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yep.**

[Part V, Article 176 of the treaty](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Versailles/Part_V#Article_176) covers closing military schools. Germany was allowed one school per arm of the military:

> On the expiration of two months from the coming into force of the present Treaty there must only exist in Germany the number of military schools which is absolutely indispensable for the recruitment of the officers of the units allowed. **These schools will be exclusively intended for the recruitment of officers of each arm, in the proportion of one school per arm**.

This allowed only three schools to remain, as they (presumably) had three military arms at the time. As explained in the rest of the treaty article, all other military-related schools needed to close:

> Consequently, and during the period fixed above, **all military academies or similar institutions in Germany**, as well as the different military schools for officers, student officers (Aspiranten), cadets, non-commissioned officers or student non-commissioned officers (Aspiranten), **other than the schools above provided for, will be abolished**.

Comment: Nice answer, although it would be good if you provided the source for your last quote.

Comment: @SJuan76: The last quote was simply more of the linked treaty article, and I updated the answer updated for clarity.

Comment: Accepted as correct.